# How do I express this function signature in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I want to write a function like this:

```js
function foo(prop: string): { [prop]: string } {
  return { [prop]: 'bar' };
}
```

Is there a way to express this in Typescript?  The above code doesn't actually work

Comment: Would `prop` be a constant string?

Comment: no, `prop` is not a constant string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
function foo<K extends PropertyKey>(prop: K): Record<K, string> {
  return { [prop]: 'bar' } as Record<K, string>; 
}
```

It needs to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function to capture the specific [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) type of `prop` in order to preserve it in the output.  The output type is the [`Record<K,V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) utility type which has keys of type `K` and values of type `V`.

You can verify that it works:

```
const baz = foo("baz"); 
baz.baz.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

Note that the return value inside the implementation had to be [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to match `Record<K, string>`; that's because there is an outstanding [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) whereby computed keys like `[prop]` get widened to `string` even when you know a more specific type like `K` in this case.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8BpRBTAHlbMAEwGdEAFAJzgAdtKoBPDbRgPgAobqaAuRDAEp+AJWwQ4lIpgA0iElEowwAczaIA3gChEiStighKSDYgDa3WgF1+AcgBGAQ0q3EAX0SOyYiVNnzFZTUAbkQAejDPEhJ6WAR+HXDImOxEAAsoKBoSXgiVGCg0kHsAOgkAWzDymAhqEjhgKDCAFUY6AGVamBommGiQbBIwgEYAZgBOABYADi03LS0JMAVEJwAvRABeZFQOACJ1vcFQrXWSs6g4AFUaOkoAYS9sDmOkxDgAa0dGLSA)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect (it contains an `as`, which I don't like), but it expresses your idea:

```
function foo<K extends {}>(prop: keyof K): K {
  return { [prop]: 'bar' } as K;
}
```

I'll edit this answer if I find something better.